# How to fix Fortnite waiting in queue?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Is it possible to avoid waiting in the Fortnite queue before being able to play?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The Fortnite queue is caused by a large influx of players all trying to log in at the same time. Because Epic Games (the developers) do not have separate login servers to differentiate between the Save the World and Battle Royale players, everyone has to go through the same queue. This can cause long wait times, regardless of which version of the game you are running (or which tier of Save the World you bought).

Comment: Any source or do you work for epicgames?

Comment: @Squareoot I think I've seen a dev state this on Reddit. And even if they haven't, it makes sense - there's a ton of people who paid for the StW portion of the game that highly disapprove of having to wait in line for free players who are not even playing the same game. If Epic had two different login servers, they could avoid that bad publicity. There's no reason for Epic to endure such bad press if they have a solution for it, but since the problem still exists, either Epic doesn't care about the bad press, or it's more cost-effective to leave the setup as is.